# I have a "label" tag inside a "summary" tag. It is not opening the details when clicked on label. How to solve?

Tags: html, html-tag-details, html-tag-summary

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56873944/anchor-tag-inside-summary-tag-not-working) question. There is no answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48538675/link-not-working-on-icon-in-a-summary-element) question also. But my question is little different here. I am just adding another element inside the `summary` and clicking on that not opening the `details`. When I click outside `label` i.e. Only on `summary` it works.

Here is my code:

```
<form action="#" id="">
        <details>
            <summary>
                <label>Filter 1</label>
            </summary>
            <div class="filter-1">
                <input type="checkbox" name="filter-1" value="a">A <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="filter-1" value="b">B
            </div>
        </details>
    </form>
```

I am basically trying to show or hide some inputs in `details` - `summary` tags.

Note:- The classes and name attributes are just there. There is no code for that.

Expected solutions:

Clicking anything inside summary tag will open details. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code is working https://jsfiddle.net/37tpfka8/

Comment: The label tag was not working but div and span tags were working. I have tested it. Click on the label tag itself, you will notice it. But the solution by [Vaibhav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7972933/vaibhav) works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`label` element is preventing click on `summary`. Add `pointer-events: none;` to label or whatever element you put inside `summary`.

```css
label {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" id="">
  <details>
    <summary>
      <label>Filter 1</label>
    </summary>
    <div class="filter-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="filter-1" value="a">A <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="filter-1" value="b">B
    </div>
  </details>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, It worked! I have another way of dealing with this, by using a div or span and it works. Any thought about this behaviour ??